# Read textfile from specific position till specific length

Tags: c#, streamreader

Due to me receiving a very bad datafile, I have to come up with code to read from a non delimited textfile from a specific starting position and a specific length to buildup a workable dataset. The textfile is not delimited in **any** way, **but** I do have the starting and ending position of each string that I need to read. I've come up with this code, but I'm getting an error and can't figure out why, because if I replace the 395 with a 0 it works..

e.g. Invoice number starting position = 395, ending position = 414,  length = 20

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"\\t.txt"))
{                    
    char[] c = null;                   
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        c = new char[20];//Invoice number string
        sr.Read(c, 395, c.Length); //THIS IS GIVING ME AN ERROR                      
        Debug.WriteLine(""+c[0] + c[1] + c[2] + c[3] + c[4]..c[20]);
    }
}
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
System.ArgumentException: Offset and length were out of bounds for the array 
                          or count is greater than the number of elements from
                          index to the end of the source collection. at
                          System.IO.StreamReader.Read(Char[] b
```

Comment: post your error message as well please - **how come you escape the backslash in a verbatim string?** `@"\\t.txt"`

Comment: Oh dont mind the \\t.txt, im using a proper path in my c#.Here is the error : {System.ArgumentException: Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.
   at System.IO.StreamReader.Read(Char[] b

Comment: @Batista you can edit your question instead by clicking the edit button beneath your question. Then you can add the error message there instead.

Comment: Sorry @Default : im fairly new here.

Comment: @Batista no need to apologize. Welcome to the community! I'll see if I can assist you..

Comment: @Batista, the trick here is that depending on your encoding it is unlikely that bytes map to characters. They only way to do this is to read the entire file as a string translate the bytes into characters using an `Encoding` (e.g. `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`) and then do a `String.Substring`. `StreamReader` does this for you and so Elastep's answer is right. I mention this only because no one else has mention this bugbear. I do not believe there is a way to do this one character at a time.

Comment: I've created a subclass of `StreamReader` that is character aware. See the answer below. I'm not looking for answer credit; I just want to help people out.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

395 is the index in c array at which you start writing. There's no 395 index there, max is 19.
I would suggest something like this.

```
StreamReader r;
...
string allFile = r.ReadToEnd();
int offset = 395;
int length = 20;
```

And then use

```
allFile.Substring(offset, length)
```

Comment: Hmmmm, thanks.I need to start reading at position 395 in my textfile though..any ideas?

Comment: is this really smart for large files?

Comment: But i need to do this line by line.. you have given me a good start.I will just read one line then do substrings then move to next line?

Comment: It will work for my textfile - max 200 lines processed daily so shouldnt really hog resources.This service just grabs the txtfile and manipulates it into a Oracle DB.

Comment: Wait, line by line? Is it newline delimited? Then I'll agree with `s = r.ReadLine();` in combination with `s.Substring(start, length);`

Comment: @Peet Yes it is newline deliminated<Thnx!

Comment: I've created a subclass of `StreamReader` that is character aware. See the answer below. I'm not looking for answer credit; I just want to help people out.

Answer (score 4):

### Please Note

`Seek()` is too low level for what the OP wants. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8614121/371917) instead for line-by-line parsing.

Also, as Jordan mentioned, `Seek()` has the issue of character encodings and varying character sizes (e.g. for non-ASCII and non-ANSI files, like UTF, which is probably not applicable to this question). Thanks for pointing that out.

---

### Original Answer

`Seek()` is only available on a stream, so try using `sr.BaseStream.Seek(..)`, or use a different stream like such:

```
using (Stream s = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
{
    s.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    s.Read(buffer, 0, length);
}
```

Comment: You aren't taking into account the encoding. Some characters will be 2, 3, or even 4 bytes long depending on the encoding. We don't live in an ASCII world anymore, and bytes don't map directly to characters.

Comment: @Jordan. Perhaps, but the question sample suggested it would be a plain `.txt` file, which is probably a fixed 8-bit encoding based on ANSI / Windows-1252 encoding.

Comment: In any case, if this is a multi-line file, then I would rather loop over the lines with `streamReader.ReadLine().Substring(offset, length)`.

Comment: It's hard to find an unencoded text file these days. Even if you create a text file in Notepad it will create a text file with a UTF-8 encoding. To create an 8-bit encoded file in .NET you have to explicitly specify ASCII. Such ASCII files are exceedingly rare so I assume that unless they say it is an ASCII file, it is UTF-8 which is fairly standard. I'm not just concerned about OP. Other people will be reading this and they may have a different encoding.

Comment: What if the block you want to seek to is more than one line?

Comment: Truth be told, I wrote this answer in response to his immediate question. In later comments to other answers you will see that I said that `Seek()` is too low-level for what he wants. He wants line-by-line parsing. He wants string.Substring(), which you already said would work with different encodings. If he wants more, he can ask a new question. Nonetheless, I will edit my answer to mention encoding...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion for you:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"\\t.txt"))
{
    char[] c = new char[20];  // Invoice number string 
    sr.BaseStream.Position = 395;
    sr.Read(c, 0, c.Length); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(new answer based on comments)

You are parsing invoice data, with each entry on a new line, and the required data is at a fixed offset for every line. Stream.Seek() is too low level for what you want to do, because you will need several seeks, one for every line. Rather use the following:

```
int offset = 395;
int length = 20;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"\\t.txt"))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        string myData = line.Substring(offset, length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this ages ago, just wanted to post the solution that was suggested

```
 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path2))
        {
          string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {             
                dsnonhb.Tables[0].Columns.Add("InvoiceNum"  );
                dsnonhb.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Odo"         );
                dsnonhb.Tables[0].Columns.Add("PumpVal"      );
                dsnonhb.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Quantity"    );


                DataRow myrow;
                myrow = dsnonhb.Tables[0].NewRow();
                myrow["No"] = rowcounter.ToString();
                myrow["InvoiceNum"] = line.Substring(741, 6);
                myrow["Odo"] = line.Substring(499, 6);
                myrow["PumpVal"] = line.Substring(609, 7);
                myrow["Quantity"] = line.Substring(660, 6);
```

Answer (score -1):

I've created a class called `AdvancedStreamReader` into my `Helpers` project on git hub here:

https://github.com/jsmunroe/Helpers/blob/master/Helpers/IO/AdvancedStreamReader.cs

It is fairly robust. It is a subclass of `StreamReader` and keeps all of that functionality intact. There are a few caveats: a) it resets the position of the stream when it is constructed; b) you should not seek the `BaseStream` while you are using the reader; c) you need to specify the newline character type if it differs from the environment and the file can only use one type. Here are some unit tests to demonstrate how it is used.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ReadLineWithNewLineOnly()
    {
        // Setup
        var text = $"ƒun ‼Æ¢ with åò☺ encoding!\nƒun ‼Æ¢ with åò☺ encoding!\nƒun ‼Æ¢ with åò☺ encoding!\nHa!";
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        var reader = new AdvancedStreamReader(stream, NewLineType.Nl);
        reader.ReadLine();

        // Execute
        var result = reader.ReadLine();

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual("ƒun ‼Æ¢ with åò☺ encoding!", result);
        Assert.AreEqual(54, reader.CharacterPosition);
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void SeekCharacterWithUtf8()
    {
        // Setup
        var text = $"ƒun ‼Æ¢ with åò☺ encoding!{NL}ƒun ‼Æ¢ with åò☺ encoding!{NL}ƒun ‼Æ¢ with åò☺ encoding!{NL}Ha!";
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        var reader = new AdvancedStreamReader(stream);

        // Pre-condition assert
        Assert.IsTrue(bytes.Length > text.Length); // More bytes than characters in sample text.

        // Execute
        reader.SeekCharacter(84);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(84, reader.CharacterPosition);
        Assert.AreEqual($"Ha!", reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
```

I wrote this for my own use, but I hope it will help other people.

Comment: It seems I need .NET 4.5.2 for this, which I do not currently have. (Also, thanks for the effort, but this is a bit overkill for parsing a simple data file, don't you think?)

Comment: I'm only using `System.IO.StreamReader` and `System.Text.Encoding` which is available in every version of .NET since 1.1. I am using async/await but you can simply remove those overrides. You will have to get rid of the C# 6 stuff if you aren't using VS2015. I'm not telling you to use my Helpers assembly itself. You can if they want to. I'm just providing a workable solution. Take the source, change it to what fits your solution. That project is open source. It is an MIT license I believe. I wouldn't be posting proprietary closed-licensed code. I would appreciate pull requests for good ideas.

Comment: @PeetBrits, It's not overkill. It is a solution to the problem itself which requires it to be very general. I didn't write this class to solve this one problem herein. I wrote it to solve a problem I was having similar to this. I write reusable code, and sometimes to be reusable you have to create a wide interface and a robust, tested implementation. That's just how I roll.

Comment: @PeetBrits, You know that Visual Studio 2015 is free unless you are an enterprise. Their community edition is free and full featured. There are good reasons to not be able to use .NET 4.5.2 or higher, but if you can I recommend it. C# 6 is wonderful.

Comment: Cool, let's leave it here in case somebody wants to use it. (I don't know who downvoted you or why.)

Comment: That was the plan. Thanks.